# build method on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

New to rails and I'm following the Depot project found in the Agile web development with rails 3.1. Everything was fine until I got lost when the book used the "build" method.

```
@cart = current_cart
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
```

My google searches led me to understand that the .build method is just a cleaner way to create a row in the table (with association between tables). But on the code above, I was expecting the code would look like something like this:

```
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product_id => params[:product_id])
```

I don't understand why the author had to store the whole row of products( product = Product.find(params[:product_id])) instead of just getting the product_id...

Is there more to it than what I can understand?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You misunderstood `build`. It's just an alias of `new`, nothing special. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/959fb8ea651fa6638aaa7caced20d921ca2ea5c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L84

`build` won't "create" a record in database, just create a new object in memory so that the view can take this object and display something, especially for a form.

For your second question, yes, your way of composing by id will work as well. But a better approach is not to trust param. Instead, verify it by finding in db at first.

Comment: I liked your answer, although nzifnab has the same answer, your tip made me a better developer :)

Comment: isn't build required when doing through associations? quite different from new

Comment: For clarification - in current Rails, `ActiveRecord::Relation#build` is aliased to `ActiveRecord::Relation#new`, but `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy#new` is aliased to `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy#build` (the opposite direction).  With an association, `build`/`new` will create the new record with the record id's appropriately associated.  So, Relation#build and Relation#new have slightly different implementations from CollectionProxy#build and CollectionProxy#new.  However, since they are aliased in both classes, then it does not matter if you use `build` or `new`.

Comment: Source reference from comment above: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L261

Comment: Build almost behaves like new, but there are edge cases. Particularly for "has_one" relationships, if there already is a "has_one :thing" related, `obj.build_thing` can delete or nullify the foreign key of the existing related item. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212840/rails-has-one-build-association-deletes-existing-record-even-if-new-record-is-no .

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and say you are entirely correct.  Either method works and will do the same thing, but your version using just `:product_id` is more efficient and requires one less database query.  That said, it might make sense if you need that `product` variable later in the code or that specific line item calls `product.{something}` later so it doesn't have to fetch it by id at that point.

However, I personally would prefer to just set the `:product_id`, I see no reason to find the object first.