# How to update an object which was built with CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables: Client, Inspection

Inspections are created through a form that returns a CollectionProxy related to a given client like so:

inspections_controller.rb

```
def create    
  @inspcetion = @client.inspections.create(inspection_params)
  redirect_to client_inspections_path(@client) 
end
```

views/inspections/_form.html

```
<%= form_for([@client, @client.inspections.build], :html => { :class => 'form' }) do |f| %>
```

Now I am wondering how to update an existing inspection. I believe that using the same form for my update method, will always create a new object -> .build

Is that right?

The url to the update method seems to call the right inspection ( /clients/cl_id/inspections/insp_id/edit), however the form that is generated appears empty (without any of the information that was included for the creation of the inspection)

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_inspection_path(inspection.client, inspection) %>
```

I believe that I have to change the form / form_for in the edit view and shouldn't render _form.html.erb, however I am completely stuck on how to accomplish this.

Here is my plain update method from inspections_controller.rb

```
def update
  @inspection = @client.inspection.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @inspection.update(inspection_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @inspection, notice: 'Inspection was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @client.inspection.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

So, how can I update an object that is part of a CollectionProxy? It can't be that hard :)

Hope that my question is concise and that somebody can help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead in your `new` and `edit` actions do this

```
def new
  @client = # query for client
  @inspection = @client.inspections.new
end

def edit
  @client = # query to fetch client
  @inspection = @client.inspection
end
```

In your partial

```
<%= form_for([@client, @inspection], :html => { :class => 'form' }) do |f| %>
```

In this way you can do this using the same partial

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it couldn't be that hard.
I'm new to rails and really enjoying this a lot.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

[`.build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761766/build-method-on-ruby-on-rails) will just create a new ActiveRecord object for that instance. It does the same as `.new`, except you have to populate the data each time.

---

From what you've got, I would say the big problem is passing the `inspections` through per client. To fix this, I would use `RSB`'s answer, and populate the `@inspection` var in the controller

It's *never* a good idea to use a `.build` method in your view, as it's not modular

Comment: Thanks for your additional post.
the .build method actually caused a lot of trouble...

Comment: It's standard procedure if you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - I can tell you more if you want