# Rails has_one build association deletes existing record even if new record is not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have seen that in Rails (5.2.1 at least) if you have a model with a has_one association to another model, the following happens:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :steering_wheel
end

class SteeringWheel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car

  validate_presence_of :name
end
```

And I have an existing car object with a steering wheel. Then I try to build a new steering wheel like so:

```
car.build_steering_wheel
```

The new steering wheel I am trying to build is not valid because I did not set the name attribute. NEVERTHELESS, Rails has deleted my existing steering wheel record from the database! I understand and rely on build association deleting the existing record when building a new one, but not when the new record is not valid.

Anyone know how to get around this? I've tried rollback in a transaction, independently creating a steering wheel record and only doing car.steering_wheel = steering wheel if it's valid.. nothing works.

Comment: why do you want to create a new one? you can update if it exists?

Comment: That's true. I am doing it this way because the controller is written in such a way that the form_tag always wants a new record. I can rewrite the controller so that it will handle create or update actions depending on whether it's a new record or an existing record.

Comment: I'm guessing this question is very much a X&Y problem and that the actual issue is that your form or controller is just plain wrong.

Comment: Not necessarily. build_associated should not delete a record if the new one fails to add because it's invalid.

Comment: rewriting the existing method will be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord does not enforce validations on associated records by default.

You have to use `validates_associated`:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :steering_wheel
  validates_associated :steering_wheel
end
```

---

```
irb(main):004:0> Car.create!(steering_wheel: SteeringWheel.new)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Steering wheel is invalid
    from (irb):4
```

Additionally if you have setup a proper foreign key on `steering_wheels.car_id` the DB will not let you do `car.build_steering_wheel` as it would orphan a record:

```
class CreateSteeringWheels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :steering_wheels do |t|
      t.belongs_to :car, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
irb(main):005:0> c = Car.create!(steering_wheel: SteeringWheel.new(name: 'foo'))
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Car Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "cars" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2018-11-08 18:53:11.107519"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-08 18:53:11.107519"]]
  SteeringWheel Create (2.4ms)  INSERT INTO "steering_wheels" ("car_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["car_id", 3], ["name", "foo"], ["created_at", "2018-11-08 18:53:11.110355"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-08 18:53:11.110355"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Car id: 3, created_at: "2018-11-08 18:53:11", updated_at: "2018-11-08 18:53:11">
irb(main):006:0> c.build_steering_wheel
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to remove the existing associated steering_wheel. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.
    from (irb):6
irb(main):007:0>
```

Comment: Validates_associated does not stop build_associated from deleting the existing record if the association you're adding is not valid. In other words it doesn't stop:
    car.build_steering_wheel
from deleting the existing steering wheel if the new steering wheel is not valid.

Comment: As I said earlier - its an X&Y problem. If you don’t want to replace it you should not be using build_steering_wheel in the first place

Comment: But I do want to replace it if what I am replacing it with is valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is the prescribed functionality of the build_associated method for has_one associations. build_associated will delete the existing association regardless of whether the new association being built is valid or not. Therefore, do not use build_associated at all if there is any circumstance during the transaction where you want the old association to persist.